# What is the difference between AudioPlayerAgent and AudioStreamingAgent?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a url of an audio and want to play it from the internet.

I see in both `AudioPlayerAgent` and `AudioStreamingAgent` I can assign a uri to the track and play it. so what is the difference between them?

```
player.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("www.example.com"), "title", "artist", "album", null);
player.Play();
```

Comment: This link may be of some help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

`AudioPlayerAgent` is an implementation of a `BackgroundAgent` specifically designed to play audio in the background.

But

`AudioStreamingAgent` is a `BackgroundAgent` that performs per-track streaming for playback.

So what does this mean? Well my interpretation is that `AudioPlayerAgent` is made to play background audio you have stored locally where as `AudioStreamingAgent` is made to stream cloud music in the background.

Comment: That is not correct. Both can be used to stream music from the web. Set the uri of your AudioTrack to be a web url, and the AudioPlayerAgent will download it.

Comment: Both CAN be used but the intention is not, which is what I said

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394039%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_PlaylistApplication) are two types of background audio applications.

- One type implements a simple playlist and passes a Uri containing the
  address of a media file to the Zune Media Queue to set the current
  track. The Uri can be local to the phone or a remote address. In
  either case, the audio needs to be of a type supported by Windows
  Phone for playback.
- The other type of background audio application uses MediaStreamSource
  to implement an audio stream to feed audio samples to the playback
  system. The format of this stream can be anything you want